# Windows Azure WorkerRole could not load file xxx.XmlSerializers from Class Library

Tags: c#, web-services, azure-worker-roles

I have a WorkerRole referencing a Class Library that calls some SOAP web services. I've been fixing various deployment errors through InteliTrace, but am coming up against this error:

could not load file or assembly 'ClassLibrary.XmlSerializers' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This works on the dev fabric, as well as being called from a seperate Console Application, though not when deployed to a production Azure instance.

The Class Library just has a couple of added 3rd party SOAP web references, and I presume it's some auto generated proxy class that's doing the serialization, but I can't work out where and what needs updating to get passed this error (and why it's only occurring on Azure production).

Anyone have any similar experiences / ideas?

Thanks a lot.

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed. Project -> Properties -> Build -> "Generate serialization assembly"